# Why char datatype is converted to bpchar automatically?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is there any possible to convert `CHAR` datatype into `bpchar` automatically?

We have seen the scenario which selected column `datatype` is `CHAR` from application end but database level `bpchar` got created.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You [shouldn't use the `char` data type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) to begin with

Answer (score 23):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

> character(n), char(n) fixed-length, blank padded

Effectively in bpchar **b** stands for blank and **p** stands for padded and `bpchar` is same as `char(n)` or `character(n)`, a blank padded to `n` length string...

More quotes:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-query.html

> bpchar (“blank-padded char”, the internal name of the character data
>   type)