# In Go, is there a difference how char and varchar datatypes of database are scanned?

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have a struct Person which has a field AccessMode of type `uint`. In the Postgres database, the datatype of AccessMode is `char(8)`.
I have written a custom Scan function for AccessMode which implements the Scanner Interface.
In the Scan function,  it is received as a `uint8` slice representation of ASCII string.
When the datatype of AccessMode is changed to `varchar(8)` in database, it is received as a `string` in the scan function. Following is the code

```
type Access uint

type Person struct {
   AccessMode Access
}

func (a *Access) Scan(val interface{}) error {
  if bb, ok := val.([]byte); ok {                                                                                                             
    return a.UnmarshalText(bb)
  }
  return errors.New("scan failed: data is not a byte slice")
}
```

**Why is it received as a string in case of varchar and uint slice in case of char datatype in the scan function?**

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't use the `char()` type to begin with. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29

Answer (score 3):

This is dependent on the driver you're using, to avoid an issue like this you need to consult the driver's documentation. For example the [`github.com/lib/pq`](https://github.com/lib/pq) driver provides a section on data types in their [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq?tab=doc#hdr-Data_Types).

- integer types smallint, integer, and bigint are returned as int64
- floating-point types real and double precision are returned as float64
- character types char, varchar, and text are returned as string
- temporal types date, time, timetz, timestamp, and timestamptz are
    returned as time.Time
- the boolean type is returned as bool
- the bytea type is returned as []byte

You'll note in the above that `lib/pq` claims to return values of the `char` type as `string`, which is true, however it may *seem* like it is not. By that I mean that in postgres there's the `char` type, and then there is the `"char"` type, and `lib/pq` in the above refers to the latter.

If possible you should avoid using `char` and `varchar` and instead use `text`.

#### When is char a char?

When you declare a column as having type `char` or `char(n)`, the actual type of the column will be `bpchar` *(blank-padded, fixed-length character type)*, which is not handled by `lib/pq` (although it probably should be).

When you declare a column as having type `"char"`, the actual type of the column will be `"char"` *(a single-byte character type intended for internal use)*, this is handled by `lib/pq` and returned as `string`.

- [Why char datatype is converted to bpchar automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421269/why-char-datatype-is-converted-to-bpchar-automatically)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

---

To shield yourself in this specific case you can use a type switch.

```
func (a *Access) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch val := src.([]byte) {                                                                                                             
    case []byte:
        return a.UnmarshalText(val)
    case string:
        return a.UnmarshalText([]byte(val))
    }
    return errors.New("scan failed: data is not a byte slice")
}
```